# convert mmmdd,yyyy string into date VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

How can I convert string mmmdd,yyyy (Apr16,2015) into date format?
Cdate and datevalue does not work here
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use Cdate and then `format()` to however you want to display. What do you mean it doesn't work? can you explain how you're using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"Apr 16 2015"` is parsable so:

```
dateStr = "Apr16,2015"
?cdate(left$(dateStr, 3) & " " & mid$(dateStr, 4, 2) & " " & right$(dateStr, 4))
16/04/2015
```

Answer (score 0):

Often I use the following methods.

```
dateStr = "Apr16,2015"
Yr = right(dateStr,4)
Mnth = left(dateStr,3)
Dy = mid(dateStr,4,5)
x = DateSerial(Yr,Mnth,Dy)
```

or

```
x = DateSerial(Year(dateStr), Month(dateStr), Day(dateStr ))
```